# Appointments don't show up in outlook calendar

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook, calendar

One of my users is having an issue with appointments in a resource mailbox pop-up that he didn't create. It wouldn't normally be a problem (just delete them, since it's actually an mailbox the previous holder of the position used as well). However, when anyone tries to look in the calendar in the normal day/week/month view, they don't appear. If you happen to know what the appointment is, you can search for it, and find out that, say, it's for 1500 on 20 Jul 09, but if you then go to the day view, there's nothing scheduled for 1500 on 20 Jul 09.

I'm looking at his calendar from my admin account, which should show everything (AFAIK). The user has owner rights to the mailbox. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- What version of Outlook?  2007 SP2 in particular has some calendar bugfixes that may help.
- View -> Current View -> Events to show all your appointments as a list, that might help to track down elusive items

Comment: Apparently someone else managed to fix the problem.